# Nginx Multilevel reverse Proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, nginx-reverse-proxy

Nginx Setup

```
AKAMAI
|                                                                    +---> Nginx port 82
|                                                                    |
 -> AWS ELB/ALB -> Nginx Server(Port 80) -> Docker (Nginx Port 81) --|
                                                                     |
                                                                     +----> Nginx port 83
```

Browser sents request on HTTPS but Nginx server running on port 82/83 receiving x-forwarded-proto/scheme  as `http` instead of `https`

Nginx Port 80 config

---

```
http {
    ...
    server {
        ...
        listen 80;
        location / {
           proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
           proxy_pass         "http://127.0.0.1:81";
        }
        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

### Nginx Port 81 config

```
server {
    listen       81;
    location ~ ^/v1/test {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:82;
        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
        break;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:83;
    }
}
```

### Nginx Port 82 Config

```
server {
    ...
    listen       82;
    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

### Nginx Port 83 Config

```
server {
    ...
    listen       83;
    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Applications running on port 82/83 are rails applications and use Passenger to serve the traffic.

Even we tried setting as below in 82/83 Nginx server configs

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Scheme https;
```